# React newb don't know if i import stylesheet correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm practicing react recently so created a simple app via react-create-app and didn't edit any configure.
What i want to do is just rendering fullcalendar so installed recommended dependencies from fullcalendar docs.
It renders the component but without its style i imported one scss file and in this scss file import stylesheet like this
`@import '~@fullcalendar/core/min.css';` just how the doc says.
But it's not working and i can't see the style in the browser dev tools.

Here is the output of scss file :

```js
exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js")(false);
// Imports
exports.i(require("-!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss!../../node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!@fullcalendar/core/main.css"), "");
exports.i(require("-!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss!../../node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css"), "");
// Module
exports.push([module.id, "\n", ""]);
```

And my scss :

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
```

When i import the stylesheets without file extension like just main and it shows the style like this in the browser dev tools but it's not working either.

```
exports = module.exports = require("../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js")(false);
// Module
exports.push([module.id, "@charset \"UTF-8\";\n.fc {\n  direction: ltr;\n  text-align: left; }\n\n.fc-rtl {\n  text-align: right; }\n\nbody .fc {\n  /* extra precedence to overcome jqui */\n  font-size: 1em; }\n\n/* Colors\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-highlight {\n  /* when user is selecting cells */\n  background: #bce8f1;\n  opacity: 0.3; }\n\n.fc-bgevent {\n  /* default look for background events */\n  background: #8fdf82;\n  opacity: 0.3; }\n\n.fc-nonbusiness {\n  /* default look for non-business-hours areas */\n  /* will inherit .fc-bgevent's styles */\n  background: #d7d7d7; }\n\n/* Popover\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-popover {\n  position: absolute;\n  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); }\n\n.fc-popover .fc-header {\n  /* TODO: be more consistent with fc-head/fc-body */\n  display: flex;\n  flex-direction: row;\n  justify-content: space-between;\n  align-items: center;\n  padding: 2px 4px; }\n\n.fc-rtl .fc-popover .fc-header {\n  flex-direction: row-reverse; }\n\n.fc-popover .fc-header .fc-title {\n  margin: 0 2px; }\n\n.fc-popover .fc-header .fc-close {\n  cursor: pointer;\n  opacity: 0.65;\n  font-size: 1.1em; }\n\n/* Misc Reusable Components\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-divider {\n  border-style: solid;\n  border-width: 1px; }\n\nhr.fc-divider {\n  height: 0;\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0 0 2px;\n  /* height is unreliable across browsers, so use padding */\n  border-width: 1px 0; }\n\n.fc-bg,\n.fc-bgevent-skeleton,\n.fc-highlight-skeleton,\n.fc-mirror-skeleton {\n  /* these element should always cling to top-left/right corners */\n  position: absolute;\n  top: 0;\n  left: 0;\n  right: 0; }\n\n.fc-bg {\n  bottom: 0;\n  /* strech bg to bottom edge */ }\n\n.fc-bg table {\n  height: 100%;\n  /* strech bg to bottom edge */ }\n\n/* Tables\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc table {\n  width: 100%;\n  box-sizing: border-box;\n  /* fix scrollbar issue in firefox */\n  table-layout: fixed;\n  border-collapse: collapse;\n  border-spacing: 0;\n  font-size: 1em;\n  /* normalize cross-browser */ }\n\n.fc th {\n  text-align: center; }\n\n.fc th,\n.fc td {\n  border-style: solid;\n  border-width: 1px;\n  padding: 0;\n  vertical-align: top; }\n\n.fc td.fc-today {\n  border-style: double;\n  /* overcome neighboring borders */ }\n\n/* Internal Nav Links\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\na[data-goto] {\n  cursor: pointer; }\n\na[data-goto]:hover {\n  text-decoration: underline; }\n\n/* Fake Table Rows\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc .fc-row {\n  /* extra precedence to overcome themes forcing a 1px border */\n  /* no visible border by default. but make available if need be (scrollbar width compensation) */\n  border-style: solid;\n  border-width: 0; }\n\n.fc-row table {\n  /* don't put left/right border on anything within a fake row.\n     the outer tbody will worry about this */\n  border-left: 0 hidden transparent;\n  border-right: 0 hidden transparent;\n  /* no bottom borders on rows */\n  border-bottom: 0 hidden transparent; }\n\n.fc-row:first-child table {\n  border-top: 0 hidden transparent;\n  /* no top border on first row */ }\n\n/* Day Row (used within the header and the DayGrid)\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-row {\n  position: relative; }\n\n.fc-row .fc-bg {\n  z-index: 1; }\n\n/* highlighting cells & background event skeleton */\n.fc-row .fc-bgevent-skeleton,\n.fc-row .fc-highlight-skeleton {\n  bottom: 0;\n  /* stretch skeleton to bottom of row */ }\n\n.fc-row .fc-bgevent-skeleton table,\n.fc-row .fc-highlight-skeleton table {\n  height: 100%;\n  /* stretch skeleton to bottom of row */ }\n\n.fc-row .fc-highlight-skeleton td,\n.fc-row .fc-bgevent-skeleton td {\n  border-color: transparent; }\n\n.fc-row .fc-bgevent-skeleton {\n  z-index: 2; }\n\n.fc-row .fc-highlight-skeleton {\n  z-index: 3; }\n\n/*\nrow content (which contains day/week numbers and events) as well as \"mirror\" (which contains\ntemporary rendered events).\n*/\n.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton {\n  position: relative;\n  z-index: 4;\n  padding-bottom: 2px;\n  /* matches the space above the events */ }\n\n.fc-row .fc-mirror-skeleton {\n  z-index: 5; }\n\n.fc .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table,\n.fc .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td,\n.fc .fc-row .fc-mirror-skeleton td {\n  /* see-through to the background below */\n  /* extra precedence to prevent theme-provided backgrounds */\n  background: none;\n  /* in case <td>s are globally styled */\n  border-color: transparent; }\n\n.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td,\n.fc-row .fc-mirror-skeleton td {\n  /* don't put a border between events and/or the day number */\n  border-bottom: 0; }\n\n.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tbody td,\n.fc-row .fc-mirror-skeleton tbody td {\n  /* don't put a border between event cells */\n  border-top: 0; }\n\n/* Scrolling Container\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-scroller {\n  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }\n\n/* TODO: move to timegrid/daygrid */\n.fc-scroller > .fc-day-grid,\n.fc-scroller > .fc-time-grid {\n  position: relative;\n  /* re-scope all positions */\n  width: 100%;\n  /* hack to force re-sizing this inner element when scrollbars appear/disappear */ }\n\n/* Global Event Styles\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-event {\n  position: relative;\n  /* for resize handle and other inner positioning */\n  display: block;\n  /* make the <a> tag block */\n  font-size: 0.85em;\n  line-height: 1.4;\n  border-radius: 3px;\n  border: 1px solid #3788d8; }\n\n.fc-event,\n.fc-event-dot {\n  background-color: #3788d8;\n  /* default BACKGROUND color */ }\n\n.fc-event,\n.fc-event:hover {\n  color: #fff;\n  /* default TEXT color */\n  text-decoration: none;\n  /* if <a> has an href */ }\n\n.fc-event[href],\n.fc-event.fc-draggable {\n  cursor: pointer;\n  /* give events with links and draggable events a hand mouse pointer */ }\n\n.fc-not-allowed,\n.fc-not-allowed .fc-event {\n  /* to override an event's custom cursor */\n  cursor: not-allowed; }\n\n.fc-event .fc-content {\n  position: relative;\n  z-index: 2; }\n\n/* resizer (cursor AND touch devices) */\n.fc-event .fc-resizer {\n  position: absolute;\n  z-index: 4; }\n\n/* resizer (touch devices) */\n.fc-event .fc-resizer {\n  display: none; }\n\n.fc-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-resizer,\n.fc-event.fc-selected .fc-resizer {\n  /* only show when hovering or selected (with touch) */\n  display: block; }\n\n/* hit area */\n.fc-event.fc-selected .fc-resizer:before {\n  /* 40x40 touch area */\n  content: \"\";\n  position: absolute;\n  z-index: 9999;\n  /* user of this util can scope within a lower z-index */\n  top: 50%;\n  left: 50%;\n  width: 40px;\n  height: 40px;\n  margin-left: -20px;\n  margin-top: -20px; }\n\n/* Event Selection (only for touch devices)\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-event.fc-selected {\n  z-index: 9999 !important;\n  /* overcomes inline z-index */\n  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }\n\n.fc-event.fc-selected:after {\n  content: \"\";\n  position: absolute;\n  z-index: 1;\n  /* same z-index as fc-bg, behind text */\n  /* overcome the borders */\n  top: -1px;\n  right: -1px;\n  bottom: -1px;\n  left: -1px;\n  /* darkening effect */\n  background: #000;\n  opacity: 0.25; }\n\n/* Event Dragging\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-event.fc-dragging.fc-selected {\n  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }\n\n.fc-event.fc-dragging:not(.fc-selected) {\n  opacity: 0.75; }\n\n/* Horizontal Events\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n/* bigger touch area when selected */\n.fc-h-event.fc-selected:before {\n  content: \"\";\n  position: absolute;\n  z-index: 3;\n  /* below resizers */\n  top: -10px;\n  bottom: -10px;\n  left: 0;\n  right: 0; }\n\n/* events that are continuing to/from another week. kill rounded corners and butt up against edge */\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event.fc-not-start,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event.fc-not-end {\n  margin-left: 0;\n  border-left-width: 0;\n  padding-left: 1px;\n  /* replace the border with padding */\n  border-top-left-radius: 0;\n  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }\n\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event.fc-not-end,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event.fc-not-start {\n  margin-right: 0;\n  border-right-width: 0;\n  padding-right: 1px;\n  /* replace the border with padding */\n  border-top-right-radius: 0;\n  border-bottom-right-radius: 0; }\n\n/* resizer (cursor AND touch devices) */\n/* left resizer  */\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event .fc-start-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event .fc-end-resizer {\n  cursor: w-resize;\n  left: -1px;\n  /* overcome border */ }\n\n/* right resizer */\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event .fc-end-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event .fc-start-resizer {\n  cursor: e-resize;\n  right: -1px;\n  /* overcome border */ }\n\n/* resizer (mouse devices) */\n.fc-h-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-resizer {\n  width: 7px;\n  top: -1px;\n  /* overcome top border */\n  bottom: -1px;\n  /* overcome bottom border */ }\n\n/* resizer (touch devices) */\n.fc-h-event.fc-selected .fc-resizer {\n  /* 8x8 little dot */\n  border-radius: 4px;\n  border-width: 1px;\n  width: 6px;\n  height: 6px;\n  border-style: solid;\n  border-color: inherit;\n  background: #fff;\n  /* vertically center */\n  top: 50%;\n  margin-top: -4px; }\n\n/* left resizer  */\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event.fc-selected .fc-start-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event.fc-selected .fc-end-resizer {\n  margin-left: -4px;\n  /* centers the 8x8 dot on the left edge */ }\n\n/* right resizer */\n.fc-ltr .fc-h-event.fc-selected .fc-end-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-h-event.fc-selected .fc-start-resizer {\n  margin-right: -4px;\n  /* centers the 8x8 dot on the right edge */ }\n\n/* DayGrid events\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nWe use the full \"fc-day-grid-event\" class instead of using descendants because the event won't\nbe a descendant of the grid when it is being dragged.\n*/\n.fc-day-grid-event {\n  margin: 1px 2px 0;\n  /* spacing between events and edges */\n  padding: 0 1px; }\n\ntr:first-child > td > .fc-day-grid-event {\n  margin-top: 2px;\n  /* a little bit more space before the first event */ }\n\n.fc-mirror-skeleton tr:first-child > td > .fc-day-grid-event {\n  margin-top: 0;\n  /* except for mirror skeleton */ }\n\n.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {\n  /* force events to be one-line tall */\n  white-space: nowrap;\n  overflow: hidden; }\n\n.fc-day-grid-event .fc-time {\n  font-weight: bold; }\n\n/* resizer (cursor devices) */\n/* left resizer  */\n.fc-ltr .fc-day-grid-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-start-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-day-grid-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-end-resizer {\n  margin-left: -2px;\n  /* to the day cell's edge */ }\n\n/* right resizer */\n.fc-ltr .fc-day-grid-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-end-resizer,\n.fc-rtl .fc-day-grid-event.fc-allow-mouse-resize .fc-start-resizer {\n  margin-right: -2px;\n  /* to the day cell's edge */ }\n\n/* Event Limiting\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n/* \"more\" link that represents hidden events */\na.fc-more {\n  margin: 1px 3px;\n  font-size: 0.85em;\n  cursor: pointer;\n  text-decoration: none; }\n\na.fc-more:hover {\n  text-decoration: underline; }\n\n.fc-limited {\n  /* rows and cells that are hidden because of a \"more\" link */\n  display: none; }\n\n/* popover that appears when \"more\" link is clicked */\n.fc-day-grid .fc-row {\n  z-index: 1;\n  /* make the \"more\" popover one higher than this */ }\n\n.fc-more-popover {\n  z-index: 2;\n  width: 220px; }\n\n.fc-more-popover .fc-event-container {\n  padding: 10px; }\n\n/* Now Indicator\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-now-indicator {\n  position: absolute;\n  border: 0 solid red; }\n\n/* Utilities\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-unselectable {\n  -webkit-user-select: none;\n  user-select: none;\n  -webkit-touch-callout: none;\n  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }\n\n/*\nTODO: more distinction between this file and common.css\n*/\n/* Colors\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-unthemed th,\n.fc-unthemed td,\n.fc-unthemed thead,\n.fc-unthemed tbody,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-row,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-content,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-list-view,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {\n  border-color: #ddd; }\n\n.fc-unthemed .fc-popover {\n  background-color: #fff; }\n\n.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-popover .fc-header,\n.fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {\n  background: #eee; }\n\n.fc-unthemed td.fc-today {\n  background: #fcf8e3; }\n\n.fc-unthemed .fc-disabled-day {\n  background: #d7d7d7;\n  opacity: 0.3; }\n\n/* Icons\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nfrom https://feathericons.com/ and built with IcoMoon\n*/\n@font-face {\n  font-family: \"fcicons\";\n  src: url(\"data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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\") format(\"truetype\");\n  font-weight: normal;\n  font-style: normal; }\n\n.fc-icon {\n  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */\n  font-family: \"fcicons\" !important;\n  speak: none;\n  font-style: normal;\n  font-weight: normal;\n  font-feature-settings: normal;\n  font-variant: normal;\n  text-transform: none;\n  line-height: 1;\n  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */\n  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;\n  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }\n\n.fc-icon-chevron-left:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-chevron-right:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-chevrons-left:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-chevrons-right:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-minus-square:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-plus-square:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon-x:before {\n  content: \"\"; }\n\n.fc-icon {\n  display: inline-block;\n  width: 1em;\n  height: 1em;\n  text-align: center; }\n\n/* Buttons\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nLots taken from Flatly (MIT): https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.css\n*/\n/* reset */\n.fc-button {\n  border-radius: 0;\n  overflow: visible;\n  text-transform: none;\n  margin: 0;\n  font-family: inherit;\n  font-size: inherit;\n  line-height: inherit; }\n\n.fc-button:focus {\n  outline: 1px dotted;\n  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; }\n\n.fc-button {\n  -webkit-appearance: button; }\n\n.fc-button:not(:disabled) {\n  cursor: pointer; }\n\n.fc-button::-moz-focus-inner {\n  padding: 0;\n  border-style: none; }\n\n/* theme */\n.fc-button {\n  display: inline-block;\n  font-weight: 400;\n  color: #212529;\n  text-align: center;\n  vertical-align: middle;\n  -webkit-user-select: none;\n  user-select: none;\n  background-color: transparent;\n  border: 1px solid transparent;\n  padding: 0.4em 0.65em;\n  font-size: 1em;\n  line-height: 1.5;\n  border-radius: 0.25em; }\n\n.fc-button:hover {\n  color: #212529;\n  text-decoration: none; }\n\n.fc-button:focus {\n  outline: 0;\n  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.25); }\n\n.fc-button:disabled {\n  opacity: 0.65; }\n\n/* \"primary\" coloring */\n.fc-button-primary {\n  color: #fff;\n  background-color: #2C3E50;\n  border-color: #2C3E50; }\n\n.fc-button-primary:hover {\n  color: #fff;\n  background-color: #1e2b37;\n  border-color: #1a252f; }\n\n.fc-button-primary:focus {\n  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(76, 91, 106, 0.5); }\n\n.fc-button-primary:disabled {\n  color: #fff;\n  background-color: #2C3E50;\n  border-color: #2C3E50; }\n\n.fc-button-primary:not(:disabled):active,\n.fc-button-primary:not(:disabled).fc-button-active {\n  color: #fff;\n  background-color: #1a252f;\n  border-color: #151e27; }\n\n.fc-button-primary:not(:disabled):active:focus,\n.fc-button-primary:not(:disabled).fc-button-active:focus {\n  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(76, 91, 106, 0.5); }\n\n/* icons within buttons */\n.fc-button .fc-icon {\n  vertical-align: middle;\n  font-size: 1.5em; }\n\n/* Buttons Groups\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-button-group {\n  position: relative;\n  display: inline-flex;\n  vertical-align: middle; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button {\n  position: relative;\n  flex: 1 1 auto; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:hover {\n  z-index: 1; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:focus,\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:active,\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button.fc-button-active {\n  z-index: 1; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:first-child) {\n  margin-left: -1px; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:last-child) {\n  border-top-right-radius: 0;\n  border-bottom-right-radius: 0; }\n\n.fc-button-group > .fc-button:not(:first-child) {\n  border-top-left-radius: 0;\n  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }\n\n/* Popover\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-unthemed .fc-popover {\n  border-width: 1px;\n  border-style: solid; }\n\n/* List View\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-unthemed .fc-list-item:hover td {\n  background-color: #f5f5f5; }\n\n/* Toolbar\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-toolbar {\n  display: flex;\n  justify-content: space-between;\n  align-items: center; }\n\n.fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {\n  margin-bottom: 1.5em; }\n\n.fc-toolbar.fc-footer-toolbar {\n  margin-top: 1.5em; }\n\n/* inner content */\n.fc-toolbar > * > :not(:first-child) {\n  margin-left: 0.75em; }\n\n.fc-toolbar h2 {\n  font-size: 1.75em;\n  margin: 0; }\n\n/* View Structure\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n.fc-view-container {\n  position: relative; }\n\n/* undo twitter bootstrap's box-sizing rules. normalizes positioning techniques */\n/* don't do this for the toolbar because we'll want bootstrap to style those buttons as some pt */\n.fc-view-container *,\n.fc-view-container *:before,\n.fc-view-container *:after {\n  box-sizing: content-box; }\n\n.fc-view,\n.fc-view > table {\n  /* so dragged elements can be above the view's main element */\n  position: relative;\n  z-index: 1; }\n\n@media print {\n  .fc {\n    max-width: 100% !important; }\n  /* Global Event Restyling\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  .fc-event {\n    background: #fff !important;\n    color: #000 !important;\n    page-break-inside: avoid; }\n  .fc-event .fc-resizer {\n    display: none; }\n  /* Table & Day-Row Restyling\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  .fc th,\n  .fc td,\n  .fc hr,\n  .fc thead,\n  .fc tbody,\n  .fc-row {\n    border-color: #ccc !important;\n    background: #fff !important; }\n  /* kill the overlaid, absolutely-positioned components */\n  /* common... */\n  .fc-bg,\n  .fc-bgevent-skeleton,\n  .fc-highlight-skeleton,\n  .fc-mirror-skeleton,\n  .fc-bgevent-container,\n  .fc-business-container,\n  .fc-highlight-container,\n  .fc-mirror-container {\n    display: none; }\n  /* don't force a min-height on rows (for DayGrid) */\n  .fc tbody .fc-row {\n    height: auto !important;\n    /* undo height that JS set in distributeHeight */\n    min-height: 0 !important;\n    /* undo the min-height from each view's specific stylesheet */ }\n  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton {\n    position: static;\n    /* undo .fc-rigid */\n    padding-bottom: 0 !important;\n    /* use a more border-friendly method for this... */ }\n  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tbody tr:last-child td {\n    /* only works in newer browsers */\n    padding-bottom: 1em;\n    /* ...gives space within the skeleton. also ensures min height in a way */ }\n  .fc tbody .fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table {\n    /* provides a min-height for the row, but only effective for IE, which exaggerates this value,\n       making it look more like 3em. for other browers, it will already be this tall */\n    height: 1em; }\n  /* Undo month-view event limiting. Display all events and hide the \"more\" links\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  .fc-more-cell,\n  .fc-more {\n    display: none !important; }\n  .fc tr.fc-limited {\n    display: table-row !important; }\n  .fc td.fc-limited {\n    display: table-cell !important; }\n  .fc-popover {\n    display: none;\n    /* never display the \"more..\" popover in print mode */ }\n  /* TimeGrid Restyling\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  /* undo the min-height 100% trick used to fill the container's height */\n  .fc-time-grid {\n    min-height: 0 !important; }\n  /* don't display the side axis at all (\"all-day\" and time cells) */\n  .fc-timeGrid-view .fc-axis {\n    display: none; }\n  /* don't display the horizontal lines */\n  .fc-slats,\n  .fc-time-grid hr {\n    /* this hr is used when height is underused and needs to be filled */\n    display: none !important;\n    /* important overrides inline declaration */ }\n  /* let the container that holds the events be naturally positioned and create real height */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-content-skeleton {\n    position: static; }\n  /* in case there are no events, we still want some height */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-content-skeleton table {\n    height: 4em; }\n  /* kill the horizontal spacing made by the event container. event margins will be done below */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event-container {\n    margin: 0 !important; }\n  /* TimeGrid *Event* Restyling\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  /* naturally position events, vertically stacking them */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event {\n    position: static !important;\n    margin: 3px 2px !important; }\n  /* for events that continue to a future day, give the bottom border back */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event.fc-not-end {\n    border-bottom-width: 1px !important; }\n  /* indicate the event continues via \"...\" text */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event.fc-not-end:after {\n    content: \"...\"; }\n  /* for events that are continuations from previous days, give the top border back */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event.fc-not-start {\n    border-top-width: 1px !important; }\n  /* indicate the event is a continuation via \"...\" text */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event.fc-not-start:before {\n    content: \"...\"; }\n  /* time */\n  /* undo a previous declaration and let the time text span to a second line */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event .fc-time {\n    white-space: normal !important; }\n  /* hide the the time that is normally displayed... */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event .fc-time span {\n    display: none; }\n  /* ...replace it with a more verbose version (includes AM/PM) stored in an html attribute */\n  .fc-time-grid .fc-event .fc-time:after {\n    content: attr(data-full); }\n  /* Vertical Scroller & Containers\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  /* kill the scrollbars and allow natural height */\n  .fc-scroller,\n  .fc-day-grid-container,\n  .fc-time-grid-container {\n    /* */\n    overflow: visible !important;\n    height: auto !important; }\n  /* kill the horizontal border/padding used to compensate for scrollbars */\n  .fc-row {\n    border: 0 !important;\n    margin: 0 !important; }\n  /* Button Controls\n  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n  .fc-button-group,\n  .fc button {\n    display: none;\n    /* don't display any button-related controls */ } }\n\n/* DayGridView\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/\n/* day row structure */\n.fc-dayGridWeek-view .fc-content-skeleton,\n.fc-dayGridDay-view .fc-content-skeleton {\n  /* there may be week numbers in these views, so no
```

Thank you for reading...

**---Edit---**

I fixed it, it wasn't the problem of the configuration it was my fault...
There was code replacing whole code inside of header tag in my app.js that's why i couldn't load any stylesheet.
Sorry commentors, but thank you for helping me anyways.

Comment: If you're using create react app you need to install node sass in order to compile the `scss` files. In your command line run: `npm install node-sass` and then try again.

Comment: @Rodrigo Thank you for reply but i installed all loader already

Answer (score 0):

First `rm-rf ./node_modules package-log.json`
Second `npm I`
Third `npm i -D node-sass`

Once everything is fine remove the `~` from the @imports
Run again, if you are using a Mac I quite often have a problem when importing `scss | css` flies there for I have to start it he path from node_modules for example if I want to import normalize.scss I do like `@import “node_modules/normalize.scss/normalize.scss”`
Something else is that if I try to import a css file into a scss file I get an error that is why a prefer to import my css files into the index.jsx of the app